# Provider in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning `redux` to manage state of the application. I am going through official docs http://redux.js.org for it.

I gotcha use of `redux` but in the usecase they have placed `<App />` inside `<Provider>`. Can anyone suggest me what `<Provider>` do ?

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import todoApp from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

let store = createStore(todoApp)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their git repository, they provide a description of what the `<Provider>` is and how it's used, please [see the link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store)

Basically, the `<Provider>` enables the [redux store](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html) for the application. So you can `connect` your containers to the `store`

Comment: What do you mean by "containers" ? Are you referencing `<App />` ?

Comment: `containers` are the react components that are connected to the redux store. using the `connect` function that Redux provides.  Please see an article about what are the differences between components and containers  https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005